# Is there a message sent to app windows when extended monitor is unplugged / switched?

Tags: c++, windows

I am having an app with a dialog. I would like to know when an extended monitor is unpluged so I can move the app window to the primary monitor, if the app was in the extended one.
I would also want to know when the user is making changes with the extended monitor position.

Is there a WM message that is posted to the window when this happens.
I'm building my app in Visual Studio C++, using the standard WINAPI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145210%28v=vs.85%29.aspx);

> The `WM_DISPLAYCHANGE` message is sent to all windows when the display
>   resolution has changed.

I'm not familiar enough with this to tell you how to use it though.